# Changing identity using Tor and Stem

Tags: python, tor, stem

I'm following the tutorial [To Russia With Love](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html), and as part of this I want to change the identity everytime I run the code. I've looked at multiple questions and tutorials and from the looks of it my torrc-defaults file is correct as it has: 
ControlPort 9151
CookieAuthentication 1

I wanted to edit the torrc file first but if i touch it Tor won't run anymore, so i read somewhere to look at torrc instead. The torrc file alone only has:

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor will ignore it
```

I don't want to set a password so my understanding from reading the stem documents is that setting the Authentication is enough. I have the following code:

```
import socks  # SocksiPy module
import socket
import requests

SOCKS_PORT = 9150

# Set socks proxy and wrap the urllib module

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', SOCKS_PORT)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

def getaddrinfo(*args):
  return [(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 6, '', (args[0], args[1]))]

socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo

url = "http://google.com"

print requests.get(url).elapsed.total_seconds()

from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9151) as controller:
    controller.authenticate()
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

But when I run it i get the error: 
socks.SOCKS5Error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure

I'm not sure what to do, i've been reading about this for hours and haven't been able to solve the problem. Any hints would be great.

EDIT:
I've also read through [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637436/tor-stem-and-sockets-changing-identity-with-tor), but it doesn't seem like there's a solution.
I also tried putting the Controller statement before setting the sockets, but in that case the IP remains the same and doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem by moving the controller statement before setting the sockets. Initially it looked like the IP remains the same but turns out if you wait an extra 3 or 4 seconds the IP changes, so I just added a time delay and it runs fine.